# call a jquery function depending on selected option

Tags: jquery

i have a tab menu with different categories:

```
    <ul class="feed-tabs">
       <li>category1</li>
       <li>category2</li>
       <li>category3</li>
       <li>category4</li>
       <li>category5</li>      
    </ul>
```

When i click in a tab it shows the corresponding div:

```
<div id="feeds-container">
    <div class="feed-category1">
        <div><p >cat1-1</p></div>
        <div><p >cat1-2</p></div>
        <div><p >cat1-3</p></div>
        <div><p >cat1-4</p></div>           
    </div>      
    <div class="feed-category2">
        <div><p >cat2-1</p></div>
        <div><p >cat2-2</p></div>
        <div><p >cat2-3</p></div>
        <div><p >cat2-4</p></div>           
    </div>
    <div class="feed-category3">
        <div><p >cat3-1</p></div>
        <div><p >cat3-2</p></div>
        <div><p >cat3-3</p></div>
        <div><p >cat3-4</p></div>           
    </div>
    <div class="feed-category4">
        <div><p >cat4-1</p></div>
        <div><p >cat4-2</p></div>
        <div><p >cat4-3</p></div>
        <div><p >cat4-4</p></div>           
    </div>
</div>
```

in that divs i want to use this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var first = 0;
        var speed = 400;
        var pause = 3500;

        function removeFirst(){
            first = $('div.feed-category1 div:first').html();
            $('div.feed-category1 div:first')
            .animate({opacity: 0}, speed)
            .fadeOut('100', function() {$(this).remove();});
            addLast(first);
        }

        function addLast(first){
            last = '<div style="display:none">'+first+'</div>';
            $('div.feed-category1').append(last)
            $('div.feed-category1 div:last')
            .animate({opacity: 1}, speed)
            .fadeIn('1000')
        }

        interval = setInterval(removeFirst, pause);
    });
</script>
```

which works as a news ticker.
Now it only works with 'feed-category1' because its hardcoded in the jquery function.

How can i make it work for all categories.

the sample code is this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.cdncast.com/anyblog/frontpagev2/js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        ul.feed-tabs { list-style:none; }
        ul.feed-tabs li { float: left; text-decoration: none; padding: 0 20px; cursor: pointer; }
        hr { clear:both; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("ul.feed-tabs").tabs("#feeds-container > div", { effect: 'fade', fadeInSpeed : 700, current : 'current', tabs : 'li' });
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){

            var first = 0;
            var speed = 400;
            var pause = 3500;

            function removeFirst(){
                first = $('div.feed-category1 div:first').html();
                $('div.feed-category1 div:first')
                .animate({opacity: 0}, speed)
                .fadeOut('100', function() {$(this).remove();});
                addLast(first);
            }

            function addLast(first){
                last = '<div style="display:none">'+first+'</div>';
                $('div.feed-category1').append(last)
                $('div.feed-category1 div:last')
                .animate({opacity: 1}, speed)
                .fadeIn('1000')
            }

            interval = setInterval(removeFirst, pause);
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <ul class="feed-tabs">
           <li>category1</li>
           <li>category2</li>
           <li>category3</li>
           <li>category4</li>
           <li>category5</li>      
        </ul>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="feeds-container">
        <div class="feed-category1">
            <div><p >cat1-1</p></div>
            <div><p >cat1-2</p></div>
            <div><p >cat1-3</p></div>
            <div><p >cat1-4</p></div>           
        </div>      
        <div class="feed-category2">
            <div><p >cat2-1</p></div>
            <div><p >cat2-2</p></div>
            <div><p >cat2-3</p></div>
            <div><p >cat2-4</p></div>           
        </div>
        <div class="feed-category3">
            <div><p >cat3-1</p></div>
            <div><p >cat3-2</p></div>
            <div><p >cat3-3</p></div>
            <div><p >cat3-4</p></div>           
        </div>
        <div class="feed-category4">
            <div><p >cat4-1</p></div>
            <div><p >cat4-2</p></div>
            <div><p >cat4-3</p></div>
            <div><p >cat4-4</p></div>           
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/dgH3S/

I modified `removeFirst` to the below code and removed the other method entirely. The trick is that I loop through all of the `div`s directly within `#feeds-container` and use `this` to target each individually.  The other modification I made is to simply move the element rather than removing it and creating a new one each time.

```
function removeFirst() {
    $("#feeds-container > div").each(function() {
        first = $(this).find('div:first').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, speed).fadeOut('100', function() {
            $(this).appendTo($(this).parent()).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, speed).fadeIn('1000');
        });
    });
}
```

Alternatively, for better performance you may want to just target the active tab instead of animating all tabs even if they are not shown.  I don't know that library well enough to tell you how to figure out which is active (may just be able to use `not(":hidden")`).

Comment: do you think it would be possible to have a non rotating div "no-rotate":
   <div class="feed-category1">
        <div><p >cat1-1</p></div>
        <div><p >cat1-2</p></div>
        <div><p >cat1-3</p></div>
        <div><p >cat1-4</p></div>           
        <div class="no-rotate"><p>cat description</p></div>           
    </div> 
so all the divs rotate and the last one stay always.

Comment: @oterox I would suggest instead wrapping the ones you do want to rotate in a div with a class to indicate that it should be rotated, something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/dgH3S/6/